# How to automatically convert "normal" conditions to yoda conditions

Tags: plugins, coding-standards

I am working on a large WordPress Plugin. It has already more than 10'000 lines of code (PHP + Javascript) and must be changed to yoda conditions, for matching the coding standards of WordPress.

Is there a program or an online tool that converts the code (Javascript + PHP) automatically to yoda conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [PHPCBF](https://phpqa.io/projects/phpcbf.html) which can automatically fix some of them at least.

However, I'd suggest ignoring Yoda conditions. There is currently a [proposal to drop yoda conditions](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/1624) from the coding standard in favour of stricter checks against assignments in control structures, while moving slowly has been well received.

Comment: Yet another more recent proposal (June 2022) that seems to show that developers mostly prefer non-Yoda: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/06/14/upcoming-disallow-assignments-in-conditions-and-remove-the-yoda-condition-requirement-for-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VS code extension called [**Yoda condition**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haruncox.yodac) to convert normal condition to Yoda condition.